# How to protect some files from the Jinja template processor?

Tags: python, cookiecutter

I am using cookiecutter to create a tornado project, using [this template](https://github.com/luizalabs/tornado-cookiecutter) (it has several bugs, so you'll probably won't be able to use it out of the box). I have hit a problem which I do not know how to solve:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char '\\' at 124272
  File "./{{cookiecutter.project_slug}}/static/swagger/lib/jsoneditor.min.js", line 10
```

I am not sure, but I have the impression that `cookiecutter` is trying to Jinja-process the `jsoneditor.min.js`, which is not supposed to happen, since the "templating" in that file is not supposed to be processed by `cookiecutter`, it just happens to include the same escape characters that `Jinja` is using.

Is it possible to tell `cookiecutter` not to process files inside a certain directory? This is probably a matter of properly setting up the `cookiecutter` template, but not sure how this can be specified.

Comment: You probably want to [copy without render](http://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/copy_without_render.html).

Comment: @syntonym: seems to work, thanks! Can you put this as answer, and I'll add a short example, upvote and accept?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default cookiecutter will try to process every file as a jinja template which produces wrong results if you have something that looks like a jinja template but is only supposed to be taken literal. Starting with cookiecutter 1.1 one can tell cookiecutter to only copy some files without interpreting them as jinja template ([documentation](http://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/copy_without_render.html)).

To do that you have to add a `_copy_without_render` key in the cookiecutter config file (`cookiecutter.json`). It takes a list of [Unix shell-style wildcards](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html). If a filename matches any of the patterns, it will be copied and not processed as a jinja template.

Example

```
{
    "project_slug": "sample",
    "_copy_without_render": [
        "*.js",
        "not_rendered_dir/*",
        "rendered_dir/not_rendered_file.ini"
    ]
}
```

This will not process any javascript files (files which end with `.js`), any files that are in the `not_rendered_dir` and not the `not_rendered_file.ini` in the `rendered_dir`. They will only get copied.

Answer (score 7):

Just came across this question and also this [Github Issue](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter/issues/9).

It seems like a nice addition, that one can partially mark parts of a file or entire template to not be processed by using the `{% raw %}` tag:

```
{% raw %}
{% comment %}Whatever jinja code goes here....{% endcomment %}
...
{% endraw %}
```